# Когда после союза "и" перед придаточным не ставится запятая?

Tags: запятые, спп, ссп

В правилах Розенталя есть предложение со следующей пунктуацией:

"Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, никто не знает".

Вопрос: как объяснить отсутствие запятой перед придаточной частью (после "и" и перед "где"), если после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Он давно уже уехал, и **где он теперь**, никто не знает* — союз И присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение (Розенталь).

1. Этот пример дается  у Розенталя в теме, посвященной встрече сочинительных и подчинительных союзов, **поэтому к присоединительным союзам  пример отношения не имеет** (эти союзы Розенталь рассматривает отдельно в  § 36.5, а это § 36.3).
2. Этот пример **действительно «выпадает» из общей темы**,  в которой решение о постановке запятой принимается формально: запятая ставится, если структура позволяет переставить придаточное, а смысл не так важен.

Вот что об этом говорит сам Розенталь: «…при изъятии придаточной части с союзом когда значение предложно-именного сочетания к нему **становится неясным,** но **в структурном отношении такое изъятие возможно,** поэтому запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзами в подобных случаях обычно ставится).

Но в данном случае **структура как раз позволяет  сделать перестановку**, тем не менее Розенталь не хочет делить СПП с придаточным изъяснительным на части, а предлагает считать **его единым целым.**

**А почему?**

3. Для ответа на этот вопрос обратимся к теме СПП с **изъяснительными** придаточными и рассмотрим тот случай, когда придаточное находится **в препозиции**. (Розенталь  еще раз касается этой темы, когда рассматривает вопрос о постановке тире в  таких СПП: Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять ).
4. **Препозиция изъяснительного придаточного  случается не так часто** (это уже материал из современного синтаксиса).

**При союзной связи** она разрешена только для **союза  ЧТО** (*что волки жадны, всякий знает*). В случае **союзных слов** (где, когда и др.) препозиция возможна, она обычно используется для выражения **экспрессии** (где он был, я понятия не имею).

Поэтому можно считать,  что **препозиция для изъяснительных придаточных – это явление особое** и в какой-то мере затрудняющее понимание структуры предложения.

5. Поэтому очень желательно **не обособлять изъяснительное придаточное,** а считать СПП единой конструкцией  (кстати, обособление предполагает **вставочную интонацию**, совсем здесь не подходящую).
6. Такое решение соответствует **общему принципу**, когда постановка запятой связана со структурой предложения, то есть учитываются **двойные союзы**, причем как подчинительные  (когда….то), так и сочинительные (не только когда…но и …).
7. **Вывод:** изъяснительное придаточное в препозиции  не обособляется (запятая перед ним не ставится),  **так как препозиция нехарактерна для этого вида СПП и может вызвать затруднение при понимании общей структуры сложного предложения.**

Answer (score 2):

Комментарий Розенталя к этому примеру (союз и присоединяет законченное СПП) опирается на правило § 36.5.1):

> 5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (*в начале предложения*, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом
>      зависит от значения союза:
>
> 1) как правило, *после союза **и** запятая не ставится*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

Если с этим правилом логически связать комментарий к примеру, то можно заключить, что в нём присоединяемое через запятую и начинающееся с "и" **полное ССП** изначально не имеет запятой после этого союза (факт присоединения не должен повлиять на внутреннюю пунктуацию присоединяемого предложения).