# Запятая между рядом расположенными союзами

Tags: запятые

Если реорганизовать текст из соответствующей главы в справочнике Розенталя, то получится следующее правило:

**ЗАПЯТАЯ НА СТЫКЕ СОЮЗОВ СТАВИТСЯ ВСЕГДА, КРОМЕ 6-ТИ СЛЕДУЮЩИХ ПУНКТОВ**:

**1. В ПОСЛЕДНЕМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ ВНУТРИ СОСТАВНОГО**

> Я не знал, где мне его искать и что у него спросить.

**2. ВТОРОЙ СОЮЗ ТАКОГО РОДА, КАК ‟ЕСЛИ ..., ТО”, ‟КОГДА ..., ТО”, ‟ЧЕМ ..., ТЕМ”, ‟ТАК КАК ..., ТО” И Т.П.**

> Он сказал, что если будет свободен, то вечером придёт ко мне.

**3. СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ ВНУТРИ ДАННОГО СОСТАВНОГО НАЧИНАЕТСЯ С ‟НО”.**

> За огородом следовали крестьянские избы, которые хотя были выстроены врассыпную и не заключены в правильные улицы, но показывали довольство обитателей (Т.).

**4. ПЕРВЫЙ ИЗ СОЮЗОВ СОЮЗ ‟А”**

> Печально поглядывал он по сторонам, и ему станови-лось невыносимо жаль и небо, и землю, и лес, а когда самая высокая нотка свирели пронеслась протяжно в воздухе и задрожала, как голос плачущего человека, ему стало чрезвычайно горько и обидно на непорядок, который замечался в природе (Ч.)

**5. ПЕРВЫЙ СОЮЗ ИЗ ДВУХ — ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ИЛИ ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ**

> Не хочется школьникам весной учиться, особенно когда тепло и ярко светит солнце.

**6. ПОСЛЕ ПРОТИВИТЕЛЬНЫХ СОЮЗОВ (‟НО”, ‟ОДНАКО”, ‟ХОТЯ”) ПИШЕТСЯ ЗАПЯТАЯ В ЗАВИСИМОСТИ ОТ ПАУЗЫ ПРИ ЧТЕНИИ**

В этой главе у Розенталя есть следующее предложение: **‟Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, никто не знает”**. Отсутствие запятой в этом предложении объясняется следующим образом: ‟союз и присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение”; это полный бред, так как почти ВСЕ предложения с запятой в этой главе присоединяют целое сложноподчиненное предложение. Ни один из вышеперечисленных пунктов также не объясняет отсутствие запятой. **Почему в этом предложении нет запятой?**

Comment: *Jim Korbett*, такой вопрос уже задавался. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452896/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f (Когда после союза "и" перед придаточным не ставится запятая?) P. S. *КРОМЕ 6-ТИ СЛЕДУЮЩИХ ПУНКТОВ* — **шесть** (количественное числительное) наращения не требует.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел; но там два очень плохих ответа.

Comment: Вы мне уже говорили про наращения, а я уже говорил вам, что не приемлю этот эту норму. Цифра 6 обозначает слово ‟шесть”, а не ‟шести”, и если я поставлю цифру, то это будет как ‟кроме шесть пунктов”, а не ‟кроме шести пунктов”. Если следовать этой норме, то вообще нельзя писать цифрами, кроме как если цифра в именительном и винительном падеже.

Comment: Просто есть негласная рекомендация: числа до десяти обычно пишут прописью.

Comment: Да, полный бред, очень маловероятно, что это писал Розенталь. Запятая должна стоять.

Comment: @oleedd https://mir-knig.com/read_232300-54 § 110. Запятая на стыке двух союзов "В предложениях типа Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю запятая после союза и не ставится". А кто же это писал? (это из издания 1994 года). Причина отсутствия запятой в этом издании не обозначена. Вот еще издание http://tlf.msk.ru/school/rozental/rozental.htm 1989 года (прижизненное). Надо бы относиться к классикам с большим уважением. Я бы не стала называть бредом все, что кажется вам непонятным – это не критерий истинности.

Comment: @Sharon Оно появилось ещё раньше. Ссылка, к сожалению, уже не работает. Началось оно с предложения классика. Надо было же объяснить пунктуацию. А на самом деле — паузы нет, и классик решил запятую не ставить. Это в книге, где соединены пунктуация и что-то ещё. Розенталь так не соединял, у него всё чётко и отдельно издавалось, в справочнике 1959 года, над которым Розенталь работал непосредственно, о таком не сказано. Получается, что его переиздавали и дополняли ещё в то время.

Comment: Вы же, наверное, в курсе, что мы запятые ставим не только по паузам. Перестановка придаточного – это формальный метод, а такие методы всегда имеют исключения  и требуют индивидуально подхода. СПП с придаточным изъяснительным в препозиции Розенталь выделял и в других темах (вроде бы при постановке тире). Так что вопрос требует серьезного подхода, изучения и внимания со стороны пользователей, если они сами не относятся к языку чисто формально, ага?

Comment: Наш участник дословно повторил уже заданный вопрос (что уже некорректно), определил данные ранее ответы как "очень плохие". Самое время и вам, и ему дать очень хорошие ответы :).

Comment: @Sharon Если ответы не подходят, то вопрос можно повторять — указав на то, почему не подходят и что надо.

Comment: Можно, но  участник должен был указать, что это ПОВТОР вопроса 2019 года  и что данные раньше ответы на этот же вопрос ему не кажутся корректными. 
 Розенталь не объяснил, почему в этом примере нет запятой.  Он сомневается, что это истинная редакция Розенталя? У него есть вариант своего ответа? Или он надеется, что кто-нибудь (очевидно, из новых участников) предложит другую версию.  Логичнее было бы предварительно поискать ответ в Интернете на других форумах,  задать вопрос на Грамоте.ру.
И все это надо было указать, чтобы не люди не думали, что это НОВЫЙ вопрос.

Comment: Примеры. (1) Хорошо бы вам, конечно, разыскать Мишу и с ним поговорить, но давненько это было, в начале мая 1973 года, и где он теперь ― не знаю. [Владимир Санин (1987)]

(2) ― Вот этого не знаю, ― пожал плечами танкист, ― этого на второй день ранили, и где он теперь ― в небе, на земле или под землей, ― мне неведомо. [Константин Симонов. (1955-1959)]